# how to install scipy for python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have Python 2.7, and I have [distutils](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html) installed.

I downloaded the latest version of [Scipy for win 32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/).

For the life of me, I do not understand how to install it.

From the [directions on the site](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Windows), it states:

> If you already have Python installed, the easiest way to install Numpy
>   and Scipy is to download and install the binary distribution from
>   [Download](http://www.scipy.org/Download).

I have followed the above directions and [downloaded this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/).

[image]

**I cannot figure what to do now!**

How do I finish getting scipy installed?

Comment: binaries end with .exe ... in windows at least ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley thank you. i did not find an EXE

Comment: thats because you didnt download it ... see my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try downloading the windows binary ...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.11.0/scipy-0.11.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you've downloaded the source distribution, which you would normally install by doing:

```
python setup.py install
```

However, without the proper C compiler environment and other libraries, it will probably fail. I'm guessing you really wanted to download the [Windows binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.11.0/scipy-0.11.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download) .

You have to drill a little further down in the sourceforge site to find it.

Comment: I dont think this will work for him unless he has the vsrallbat.dll or whatever it is from microsoft...

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

This is a helpful site with a number of binaries for scientific python computing in one place.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be well off installing [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). Makes installing almost anything python-related a breeze!

e.g.

```
easy_install scipy
```

There's another one called pip.

```
easy_install pip

pip install scipy
```

Comment: i think i have that already! how would i use it to install scipy?

Comment: I dont think this will work for him unless he has the vsrallbat.dll or whatever it is from microsoft... (in this case...) but in general yes setuptools is a win

Comment: awesome!!!! can you tell me how did you know it was scipy and not scipy1.01 or something like that?

Comment: To be honest I just know it from having used easy_install and pip a lot and they don't include version numbers - just easy to remember names. In case you *do* need to use a version number, it's easy as `easy install scipy==0.9` (pseudo version number)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Ah, the dreaded vcvarsall.bat error. Yeah, sometimes it messes you up. But easy_install works a lot better than pip on Windows for some reason

Comment: Try `easy_install scikit-learn`. Before you ask - Found it by Googling "sklearn pypi". [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypihttp://pypi.python.org/pypi) is the source of this awesomeness.

Answer (score 0):

just open windows command prompt and go to the directory you have installed Python. e.g 
`c:\python34>`

Once there, just type `python -m pip install scipy` and press enter