# Calculate t-value within a pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I came across a block of code for t-value calculation at [Python function to get the t-statistic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339305/python-function-to-get-the-t-statistic).

I am trying to calculate the t-value for values in a column in my PySpark data frame and store in a new column using the below,

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from scipy import stats
Weighted_df = Weighted_df.withColumn('n-1', F.col('Total_Patient_Number')-1)
Weighted_df = Weighted_df.withColumn('t_value', stats.t.ppf(1-0.025, (F.col('n-1'))))

However, when I run the code, I get the following error "ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.". I know the problem is from F.col('n-1') but can't seem to figure it out.